# Return min(DATE) if Date does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, case, min

In Oracle SQLDeveloper, I am trying to run a query where I find return a specific date as the StartDate, but return the minimum date if the earliest existing date is greater than the specified start date. I tried doing this using a CASE statement, but I keep getting a "missing right parentheses" error. Here's my code thus far:

```
select 
  a.program
  , a.match_file
  , (case when b.date = '27-JAN-13' then b.date else min(b.date end)) as Startdate
from Schema1.program a, Schema1.detail b
where a.match_file = b.matchfile
  and (case when b.date=' ' then min(b.date) else b.date end) = '27-JAN-13'
  group by a.program, a.match_file
;
```

Can someone please let me know if I'm going about this wrong? I have also tried using IF statements and a couple different UNION statements, but I can't get it to return what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to consider the COALESCE function (picks the first non-null argument). However, if you are filtering against blanks instead of nulls, this may not work. In that case, the CASE statement should suit your needs.

In your code the "end" in your first case statement is inside the min(), which might be why you are getting the error.

```
, (case when b.date = '27-JAN-13' then b.date else min(b.date) end) as Startdate
```

I'm having trouble figuring out what you are trying to do, but based on your description I have come up with the below sql. I don't think you need to do any filtering in your where clause, since you want every single row result. You just want to know for each program/file combo, if the earliest date is after Jan 27th. The case statement in the select takes care of this.

> "return a specific date as the StartDate, but return the minimum date
>   if the earliest existing date is greater than the specified start
>   date"

```
select 
    a.program
    , a.match_file
    , case when min(b.date) > '27-JAN-13' then min(b.date) else '27-JAN-13' end as Startdate
from Schema1.program a, Schema1.detail b
where a.match_file = b.matchfile
group by a.program, a.match_file;
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, maybe first answer or solve OP question and then add the recomendation. I was confussed trying to see how the coalesce solve the problem.  Still your answer look correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply pkm! I tried running your query, but I got [Error ORA-00932](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330123/lookup-error-ora-00932-inconsistent-datatypes-expected-date-got-number). I tried using to_date() to fix this, but I still got the same error.

Comment: Oh wait! The to_date function did work! I just had to use a recognizable date format.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is syntactically incorrect.
Move the `end` outside of the min aggregate as per below

```
select 
  a.program
  , a.match_file
  , (case when b.date = '27-JAN-13' then b.date else min(b.date) end) as Startdate
from Schema1.program a, Schema1.detail b
where a.match_file = b.matchfile
  and (case when b.date=' ' then min(b.date) else b.date end) = '27-JAN-13'
  group by a.program, a.match_file
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I fixed the syntax and ran it again, but now I get "Error ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here." :(
Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that part. You can't have an aggregate function in a where clause. Take `and (case when b.date=' ' then min(b.date) else b.date end) = '27-JAN-13'` out of your query.